# Create a numbered grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I am a PHP developer learning c#, im starting with making a bingo game in c# using wpf.

At the moment, I need to make the number grid, so a grid of squares with the numbers 1-90 in them.

At the moment, I have a window MainGame, and I am using items from the toolbox, such grid, but cant work out an easy way to get 90 of the aligned nicely without having lots of tedious work. ONly way I know how is to drag 90 rectangles onto the window, but this is far from efficient.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: there are several plotting libraries you can use. One i use which is well documented is oxyplot. Have a look at it. http://www.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/

Comment: @Naresh is there a place in your link where the source code can be downloaded ?

Comment: sure.. its free to use.. https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not simply create a collection of numbers and put this as itemssource to an itemscontrol?

```
public List<int> MySquares {get;set;} //todo: initialize with your numbers 1-90
```

xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MySquares}">
```

you can choose an ItemsPanel(eg. WrapPanel) from your choice for alignment and create an ItemTemplate for your numbers

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```